# Issues with running script without credentials dialog box

Tags: powershell, powershell-ise

I'm trying to run through a powershell script that creates a computername and places that computer in the right OU in AD. The only issue is I need to enter credentials for this to happen, but I want to do it without having to enter the credentials into the powershell credential dialog box.

I used the System.Management.Automation.PSCredential, but that is was apparently was giving me the dialog box.

```
$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString 'xxxxxx' -AsPlainText -Force
$mycreds = New-Object System.Managemnet.Automation.PSCredential("xxxx", $secpasswd)
```

Trying to the use the code above without a dialog box popping up

> New-Object : Cannot find type [System.Managemnet.Automation.PSCredential]: verify that the assembly containing this type is loaded.
>   At line:2 char:12
>   + $mycreds = New-Object System.Managemnet.Automation.PSCredential("xxxx ...
>   +~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ + CategoryInfo          : InvalidType: (:) [New-Object], PSArgumentException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand

Comment: I think you've made a typo: Managemnet should be Management

Comment: This might help: [Using saved credentials securely in PowerShell scripts](https://blog.kloud.com.au/2016/04/21/using-saved-credentials-securely-in-powershell-scripts/)

Comment: @bluuf even if I fix that typo, won't a powershell credentials dialog box pop up still?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made a typo on "Managemnet". It should be -

$mycreds = New-Object System.**Management**.Automation.PSCredential("xxxx", $secpasswd)

Answer (score 0):

It appears you made a typo in your code: `Managemnet` should be `Management`, as in `System.Management.Automation`. That is why your error is being thrown.

However, there is no need to use the full definition for `PSCredential`. Use the following instead:

```
$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString 'xxxxxx' -AsPlainText -Force
$mycreds = New-Object PSCredential("xxxx", $secpasswd)
```

This does not show a dialog box.